# Specifying main class via java -cp *.jar package.path.ClassName won't work

Tags: java

I know that there are a lot of questions for this topic out there, although I have tried a lot of things, I cannot figure out where the problem is.

Specifically I try to execute the jar file of [webgraph](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22it.unimi.dsi%22) using

```
java-cp webgraph-3.5.2.jar it.unimi.dsi.webgraph.ASCIIGraph
```

I looked in the jar-file and the class file is present in the it/unimi/dsi/webgraph folder, which seems to be OK. When running the command I still get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class it.unimi.dsi.webgraph.ASCIIGraph
```

I tried to specify all the libs separated by a semi-colon, which didn't help (I would also expect another error message for missing libs)

Comment: is there a MANIFEST.MF file present in your jar package?

Comment: A class must have `public static void main` method for it to run from command line as you are trying. It seems that `it.unimi.dsi.webgraph.ASCIIGraph` does not have such a method and is not meant to but run.

Comment: ASCIIGraph has a main method, a MANIFEST.MF is present

Comment: there are many dependency of this class, you need download them all and add to classpath. see the pom of webgraph

Comment: that's what I meant with "tried to specify all the libs separated by a semi-colon, which didn't help"

I managed to start it from bash by importing it as ant project in eclipse and looking at the command eclipse uses:
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/.../Dev/webgraph-3.5.2/build:/home/...workspace_java/webgraph/bin:/home/.../Dev/webgraph-3.5.2/jars/compile/commons-collections.jar:more-librareies it.unimi.dsi.webgraph.ASCIIGraph
I still don't really understand why java -cp with all the libraries didn't work.

Comment: As soon as I leave out the build folder (switching the bin folder for the jar works) I get an ClassNotFoundException: IllegalStateException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run through the same problem and I finally figured it out after so many researches. Here is the way to pass that error. 
 
step one: Download and extract Apache Maven binaries from [Here](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) 
step two: Download the dependencies tarball from [here](http://webgraph.di.unimi.it/) and extract it 
step three: Retrieve the WebGraph framework source code with extensions from [this repository](https://github.com/lhelwerd/WebGraph). The version contains the copy list and copy flags compression formats, as well as additional flags for the other compression schemes. 
step four: Compile the JAR file of the framework using Maven by running "mvn install" within the WebGraph root directory. 
step five: Copy the target/webgraph-3.5.2.jar file in to the same location as the JAR files from the dependencies [the tarball dependencies]. 
 
here is the trick now, you need to specify exactly where the tarball dependencies are in order to get your expected result. Hence, assuming my tarball dependencies are in my '~/webgraph-deps/' directory,

```
$ java -cp "~/webgraph-deps/*" it.unimi.dsi.webgraph.ASCIIGraph <WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_DO>
```

Plus, if the above command fails, it might be because of running out of memory and use the following command [it will set initial heap size for Java to work on, I have 12GB of RAM and allocated 6GB for this process (-Xmx6G)]

```
$ java -Xmx6G -cp "~/webgraph-deps/*" it.unimi.dsi.webgraph.ASCIIGraph
```

Here is my reference, https://github.com/lhelwerd/WebGraph. check it out for more!!